# R Logical Indexing

Tags: r

I have some data in a dataframe called rio.tables$optionstable and this is an example of it.

```
        V1         V2   V3       V4    V5    V6    V7     V8           V9          V10
1     Code Expirydate  P/C Exercise   Bid Offer  Last Volume Openinterest Margin Price

32  RIOPS7 18/12/2014  Put   50.000 0.090 0.185 0.150     20        3,023        0.075

42  RIOJY8 18/12/2014  Put   53.000 0.365 0.475 0.470     50        3,577        0.215

173 RIOC19 29/01/2015  Put   53.000 1.335 1.450 1.360     50          646        0.950

175 RIOB29 29/01/2015  Put   54.000 1.640 1.760 1.675     50          378        1.190
```

I am only interested in one date such as 18/12/2014 so I have set:

```
EXP = rio.tables$optionstable[2] == "18/12/2014"
```

and I want to see if anything is in column 8 (Volume) so I set

```
VOL = rio.tables$optionstable[8] != ""
```

But when I try the following:

```
rio.tables$optionstable[EXP,VOL,]
```

following error occurs:

> Error in `[.data.frame`(rio.tables$optionstable, EXP, VOL, ) : 
>    undefined columns selected

it does not work. I can, however, get either EXP or VOL but not the two of them.

Answer (score 0):

If you need their intersection use

```
rio.tables$optionstable[EXP & VOL,]
```

If you need both of them

```
rio.tables$optionstable[EXP | VOL,]
```

Comment: Thank you so very much. The top reply did the trick. It never occurred to me that the & would work in that way.